# AWS CLI doesn't find config file when running in batch file after maven command

Tags: maven, batch-file, aws-cli

When I just run the `aws lambda update-function-code` command in the cmd with the appropriate parameters everything works fine. It also works when I run the command in a batch file. But when I want to run `mvn package` before `aws lambda update-function-code` in a batch file I get the following error:

'You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure"'

I already configured it and I know it is correctly configured, otherwise by just running the aws lambda command it would also throw an error. 
The config file is also at the location Amazon suggest it.

My batch file looks like this:

```
call mvn package
call aws lambda update-function-code --function-name <functionName> --zip-file fileb://<path/to/jar>
```

(Of course the words in brackets are just placeholder)

Comment: In your [`~/.aws.config`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html) file, do you specify the region?

Comment: Yes I did specify the region

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the AWS region as a [command line option](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-command-line.html) in the batch file

```
call aws --region us-east-1 lambda update-function-code --function-name <functionName> --zip-file fileb://<path/to/jar>
```

Any kind of switching of regions could be handled by logic in the batch file

Comment: Yes you could do that too but then it would also need the acces-key-id and the secret-access-key as a paramater as well. But I think it's not a good idea to store these two in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! 
Maven sets some local variables which affects in some way the aws lambda command. Because of `call`, these variables persist till the batch file is completly executed. To avoid that these variables are set till the end I had to add `@SETLOCAL` and `@ENDLOCAL` as follows:

```
@SETLOCAL
call mvn package
@ENDLOCAL
call aws lambda update-function-code --function-name <functionName> --zip-file fileb://<path/to/jar>
```

Now everything works like a charm.